# extern declaration of a function vs #include of the entire .h file

Tags: c++, extern

What is the advantage in that? Less allocation of memory because you don't include the whole file?

What if I have:

FileA.cpp:

```
extern void foo();
... 
// Somewhere in the code
void AnotherFunction
{
    ...
    foo();
    ...
}
```

FileB.h:

```
extern "C" void foo()
{
     //Something something
}
```

Can't I just #include the FileB? Or is extern better?

Thank you!

Comment: These declarations are not compatible because one of them has C linkage while the other has C++ linkage.

Comment: `(extern) void foo();` should be written once, in a `.h` header file (safe guards against changes in function parameters). Entire definitions in a `.c` source file, including its own header. The rest is unprofessional IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Using `extern` instead of including the header file can improve compile time because less files have to be opened and the preprocessed files that have to be compiled are smaller. Preprocesses files can contain hundreds of thousands of lines, so if you can eliminate some includes, that can have a noticeable effect.

By default, you should use `#include` to avoid duplicating code and to make it easier to find where `foo()` is defined. On modern computers, the speed difference is often neglible, so writing easily maintainable code is a better idea.